# Bash checking for file write completion before acting

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running Tcpdump to generate a new file every 60 sec. At the same time i'm running a bash script to process files generated by Tcpdump, but before acting i should check for file write completion. 
I'm using "fuser" but i find out that it's always returning 1 (with the old files and with the new file that is still being written by tcpdump). Can anyone tell me how can i solve it

```
#!/bin/bash

FULLPATH=$1
echo $FULLPATH

for file in $FULLPATH/*.pcap
   do
       echo "file name: $file"

       fuser $file
       result=$?
       echo $result

       if [ $result = 0 ]; then
           echo "There are no processes accessing file: $file"    
           sudo /usr/src/nDPI/example/ndpiReader -i $file
           echo "end: $file" 
           #rm-f $file

       else

          echo "file $file is in use." 
       fi

   done
```

Comment: Since the time rate in question is 60 seconds, have you thought of checking the file's modification time to see when its been updated?

Answer (score 1):

Consulting `fuser`'s manual reveals that

> fuser returns a non-zero return code if none of the specified files is accessed or in case of a fatal error

So getting a non-zero code is probably nice, but you might want to check the output too, to distinguish fatal errors from the file being used :

```
ouput=$(fuser $file)
return_code=$?

if [ "$return_code" -ne 0 ]; then
  if [ -n "$output"]; then
    echo "The file is being used"
  else
    echo "A fatal error occured !"
  fi
else
  echo "The file is not being used"
fi
```

If you don't care about fatal errors (after all, you should probably not try to read the file if one occured), then checking that the return code is non-zero should be enough.

To summarize and rephrase it, `fuser` will :

- return 0 if the file is being accessed by other process, and output a list of these
- return something else if the file is not being accessed, or if a fatal error occured

  - the code will probably be 1 if the file is not being accessed, however this is not documented
  - the code will probably be something else than 0 or 1 if a fatal error occured, however this is not documented

Comment: Thx this code will help me to check fatal errors. But, my problem is that i should wait for the end of writing a new file (by tcpdump), to begin a new process

Comment: Yeah sure, just check that the return code is non-zero. It might be better if you check that it is 1, which should probably not be the case for fatal errors, or you can also check the output. I've really explained it all in my answer, I suggest you read it again if you don't see how that helps you checking if the file is currently accessed.

Comment: @Sana I've edited my answer to summarize `fuser`'s behavior, hope that helps.

Comment: @Sana only the one currently accessed. You should check it's output and look which process are accessing them. Maybe is it your own script? Or maybe Tcpdump doesn't release the files cleanly when it has stopped writing them?

Comment: Maybe! i'll check for that

Comment: although i'm just using a simple cmd for Tcpdump: sudo /usr/src/tcpdump*/tcpdump -i eth1 -s0 -G 60 -w /home/cloudera/test/_%H_%M_%S.pcap